# Suma datos con condicional de una tabla en Consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo 3 tablas `producto` donde se registran los productos, `tipoF` donde están todos los tipos de documentos ejemplos: factura, remision, etc y `venta` donde se registran las ventas tomando el id del producto idproducto y el tipo tipof

Aqui estan las tablas y la consulta tal cual  como quiero que me las muestre

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE producto (
  idproducto INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO producto  VALUES 
(1,'TV'),
(2,'DVD'),
(3,'PC'),
(4,'LAPTOP'),
(5,'CELL'),
(6,'MICRO');


CREATE TABLE venta (
  productoID INT,
  cantidad INT,
  tipof INT
);

INSERT INTO venta  VALUES 
(1,60,1),
(1,30,1),
(2,16,2),
(2,16,3),
(3,10,2),
(3,10,1),
(4,10,2),
(4,5,2),
(5,5,2),
(6,18,3);

CREATE TABLE tipoF (
  tipo INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO tipoF VALUES 
(1,'Factura'),
(2,'Remision'),
(3,'OS');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT  
    p.idproducto, 
    p.nombre,
    v.total,
    v.Factura,
    v.Remision,
    v.OS
FROM producto AS p
        
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT productoID, SUM(cantidad) AS Total,
                SUM(CASE WHEN tipof=1 THEN cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS  Factura,
                SUM(CASE WHEN tipof=2 THEN cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS  Remision,
                SUM(CASE WHEN tipof=3 THEN cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS  OS
            FROM    venta
            GROUP BY productoID
        ) AS v ON p.idproducto = v.productoID;
```

| idproducto | nombre | total | Factura | Remision | OS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TV | 90 | 90 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | DVD | 32 | 0 | 16 | 16 |
| 3 | PC | 20 | 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 4 | LAPTOP | 15 | 0 | 15 | 0 |
| 5 | CELL | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 6 | MICRO | 18 | 0 | 0 | 18 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

En mi consulta la suma del `venta.tipof`  lo hago manual, el problema es que quiero traer el datos de la tabla `tipoF` ya que si esta tabla crece no seria algo practico hacerlo manual, como hago para que la suma del tipo se haga de manera dinámica dependiendo de la tabla `tipoF`

Comment: tipoF es una tabla o columna?

Comment: `tipoF` es una tabla, tipof es una columna en la tabla `venta` que hace referencia a la columna tipo de `tipoF`.

Answer (score 1):

¿Y te serviría algo así?

```
+------------+--------+-----------+----------+
| productoID | nombre | tipoF     | Subtotal |
+------------+--------+-----------+----------+
|          1 | TV     | Factura   |       90 |
|          2 | DVD    | Remisión  |       16 |
|          2 | DVD    | OS        |       16 |
|          3 | PC     | Remisión  |       10 |
|          3 | PC     | Factura   |       10 |
|          4 | LAPTOP | Remisión  |       15 |
|          5 | CELL   | Remisión  |        5 |
|          6 | MICRO  | OS        |       18 |
+------------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Para conseguirlo tendrías que lanzar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT productoID,nombre,tipoF,Subtotal FROM (
    SELECT productoID,nombre tipoF,
      SUM(cantidad) Subtotal
      FROM (
        SELECT productoID,tipoF,
          SUM(cantidad) cantidad
          FROM venta
          GROUP BY 1,2   
      ) c1 JOIN tipoF ON c1.tipoF=tipo
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c2 JOIN producto ON productoID=idproducto
  ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Si necesitas que quede en horizontal, puedes pivotar la tabla con un `GROUP_BY`:

```
SELECT productoID,nombre,
  SUM(Subtotal) Total,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tipoF) Tipos,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Subtotal) Subtotales
  FROM (
    SELECT productoID,nombre,tipoF,Subtotal FROM (
        SELECT productoID,nombre tipoF,
          SUM(cantidad) Subtotal
          FROM (
            SELECT productoID,tipoF,
              SUM(cantidad) cantidad
              FROM venta
              GROUP BY 1,2   
          ) c1 JOIN tipoF ON c1.tipoF=tipo
          GROUP BY 1,2  
      ) c2 JOIN producto ON productoID=idproducto  
  ) c3 GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+------------+
| productoID | nombre | Total | Tipos             | Subtotales |
+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+------------+
|          1 | TV     |    90 | Factura           | 90         |
|          2 | DVD    |    32 | Remisión,OS       | 16,16      |
|          3 | PC     |    20 | Remisión,Factura  | 10,10      |
|          4 | LAPTOP |    15 | Remisión          | 15         |
|          5 | CELL   |     5 | Remisión          | 5          |
|          6 | MICRO  |    18 | OS                | 18         |
+------------+--------+-------+-------------------+------------+
```

Tal vez si todas las filas tuvieran el mismo número de columnas, te resultaría más útil. Habría que hacer un producto cartesiano tal que así:

```
SELECT productoID,producto,
  SUM(subtotal) Total,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tipo ORDER BY tipoF) tipos,
  GROUP_CONCAT(subtotal ORDER BY tipoF) subtotal
  FROM (
    SELECT productoID,tipoF,
      IFNULL(subtotal,0) subtotal 
      FROM (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT tipo tipoF FROM tipoF  
          ) c1 JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT productoID FROM venta
          ) c2  
      ) c3 LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT productoID,tipof,
          SUM(cantidad) subtotal
          FROM venta
          GROUP BY 1,2  
      ) c4 USING(productoID,tipoF)  
  ) c5 JOIN (
    SELECT idproducto productoID,
      nombre producto
      FROM producto
  ) producto USING(productoID)
  JOIN (
    SELECT tipo tipoF,nombre tipo
      FROM tipoF
  ) tipoF USING(tipoF)
  GROUP BY productoID;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+------------+----------+-------+----------------------+----------+
| productoID | producto | Total | tipos                | subtotal |
+------------+----------+-------+----------------------+----------+
|          1 | TV       |    90 | Factura,Remisión,OS  | 90,0,0   |
|          2 | DVD      |    32 | Factura,Remisión,OS  | 0,16,16  |
|          3 | PC       |    20 | Factura,Remisión,OS  | 10,10,0  |
|          4 | LAPTOP   |    15 | Factura,Remisión,OS  | 0,15,0   |
|          5 | CELL     |     5 | Factura,Remisión,OS  | 0,5,0    |
|          6 | MICRO    |    18 | Factura,Remisión,OS  | 0,0,18   |
+------------+----------+-------+----------------------+----------+
```

Añadiendo un nuevo tipo:

```
INSERT INTO tipoF (tipo, nombre)
  VALUES (4,'Test');
```

Obtendríamos este resultado:

```
+------------+----------+-------+---------------------------+-----------+
| productoID | producto | Total | tipos                     | subtotal  |
+------------+----------+-------+---------------------------+-----------+
|          1 | TV       |    90 | Factura,Remisión,OS,Test  | 90,0,0,0  |
|          2 | DVD      |    32 | Factura,Remisión,OS,Test  | 0,16,16,0 |
|          3 | PC       |    20 | Factura,Remisión,OS,Test  | 10,10,0,0 |
|          4 | LAPTOP   |    15 | Factura,Remisión,OS,Test  | 0,15,0,0  |
|          5 | CELL     |     5 | Factura,Remisión,OS,Test  | 0,5,0,0   |
|          6 | MICRO    |    18 | Factura,Remisión,OS,Test  | 0,0,18,0  |
+------------+----------+-------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: muy buen tu aporte, el problema es que siento que redundan un poco los resultados, asi lo veo, solo quiero que el `productoID` me muestre los productos `idproducto` y no el tipo, si ves en tu solucion en la columna nombre aparecen los tipos Factura, Remision y OS, deberian solo aparecer en la columna `Tipos`, me podria servir muchismo tu solucion para implementarlo de otra forma, claro haciendo los ajustes descrito pero si se mostrase como plante al principio, seria mucho mejor ya que siento que si visualiza mejor.

Comment: Bueno, hay una diferencia importante: esta consulta se adapta a un número variable de tipos y la tuya es fija. Tal vez si todas las filas tuvieran el mismo número de columnas, te resultaría más útil. Habría que hacer un producto cartesiano en algún punto, pero podría lograrse algo más parecido a lo tuyo de forma también automática...

Comment: Si, esa es la idea que no sea fija, como tu solución, lo plantee de esa forma para dar una idea del resultado final como lo quería, gracias por el aporte y estaré trabajando mas para lograr un resultado lo mas parecido posible a como lo quiero mostrar, de igual forma cualquier otro aporte seria muy importante. Buena aporte y solución.

Comment: Veo que has modificado el dataset corrigiendo la errata de la tabla `tipoF`. Te he ampliado la respuesta con el producto cartesiano que te había sugerido. Prueba añadiendo un nuevo tipo para ver si te resulta útil.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una consulta dinámica a partir de un cursor para los tipos, por lo que tendría que ser dentro de un procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE totalesPorTipo()
BEGIN
   DECLARE vDetener INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE vTipo INT;
   DECLARE vNombre VARCHAR(10);

   DECLARE curTipos CURSOR FOR
      SELECT tipo
           , nombre
        FROM tipoF;

   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
      FOR NOT FOUND SET vDetener = 1;
         
   SET @vStmt = 'SELECT productoID idproducto
                      , ( SELECT nombre
                            FROM producto
                            WHERE idproducto = productoID
                        ) nombre
                      , sum(cantidad) Total
                ';
   
   OPEN curTipos;
   cicloTipos: LOOP
      FETCH curTipos INTO vTipo, vNombre;
      IF vDetener THEN
         LEAVE cicloTipos;
      END IF;      
      SET @vStmt = concat( @vStmt
                         , ', sum( if(tipof='
                         , vTipo
                         , ',cantidad,0) ) '
                         , vNombre 
                         );
   END LOOP;
   SET @vStmt = concat( @vStmt
                      , ' FROM venta GROUP BY productoID'
                      ); 
   PREPARE stmt FROM @vStmt;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
```

Obtendrás el resultado que necesitas al invocar:

```
call totalesPorTipo;
```

Con el script SQL que proporcionaste es difícil resistirse a corresponderle con un [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4tmhS5VgT46Q9pL942R6fc/0).

Comment: Nunca me han gustado los cursores, pero tengo que reconocer que éste es el momento de usarlos... Muy buen aporte :)